# How to accept an input at the end of a loop to re-execute the loop or not C#

Tags: c#, loops, console-application

I'm trying to figure out how to, at the end of a loop in a console app, I can accept input from a user to re-execute the loop or not with a Y/N question.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool executeLoop = true;

while (executeLoop)
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine("Again? (Y/N)");
    string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

    while (input != "N" && input != "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Again? (Y/N)");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    if (input == "N")
    {
        executeLoop = false;
        // can also just write "break;"
    }
}
```

This part validates the answer is either Y or N:

```
while (input != "N" && input != "Y")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Again? (Y/N)");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And you can also remove that part, so that every input other than "N" will continue the loop.

Another easy way is:

```
while (true)
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine("Enter \"Y\" to continue...");

    if (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() != "Y")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

So that the loop will be executed until the user enters anything other than "Y".

Answer (score 3):

Use `Console.ReadKey` to get key input from user:

```
while (true)
{
     Console.Write("End program Y/N: ");
     char input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
     if (input == 'Y' || input == 'y') break;

     Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadKey` causes many times for unexpected behavior. If you type "Y" and then click enter, then the first time you check for input it will have the value 'Y', and the second time '\r' and then '\n' (depending on environment). It is best to use `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I don't see any issue, just copy it and run, you will see

Comment: Try inputting "NNY" as a single answer. It will read N, then N, then Y, while it was only just one answer. You wouldn't want to run the loop 3 times just for that.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Did you try that? How can it read 3 letters, when I just use `ReadKey`?

Comment: It reads them one by one, that is what I'm saying. It will read "N", and then ask for input and read the already entered 2nd "N", without giving you time to type in, and then again with a "Y". I can't test it right now, but I know that this is how it worked in .Net2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

do a do while loop.

```
do 
{
  //do other stuff first
  //then get input to Y and N question and set it
} while (input == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
string s;
    do
    {
        // some statements
       s = Console.ReadLine();
    } while(s=="yes");
```

Comment: You can do `flag = s == "yes"` instead of the if-else part.

Comment: I can only assume that the downvoter did it because your code was formatted horrifyingly. Make sure your code is readable.

Comment: while requires boolean value for testing tht's why i used flag & yes differently

Comment: How is that relevant to any of the above?

Comment: So you didn't understand what I said. You can write `flag = s == "yes"` instead of `if (s.Equals("yes")) flag = true; else flag = false;`. It does the same logic and is more concise.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: no u r wrong , u cant assign string value to boolean type

Comment: `s == "yes"` is calculated into true/false and then put into the flag variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "break" command when you want to break out of a loop. note that each break will only break you out of the smallest loop you are in.

```
        int count = 0;
        string myentry = "";
        for (count = 1; count < 10; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("count=" + count);
            Console.WriteLine("Continue? Enter \"Y\" or \"N\"");
            myentry = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (myentry=="N")
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    if(!somecondition){ continue; }

    DoSomething();

    Console.WriteLine("Do something again? (y = yes)");
}
while(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
```